# how to get a string from split line and compare in python

Tags: python

I have a line after split like in here:

```
lineaftersplit=Jan 31 00:57:07 2012 GMT
```

How do I get only year 2012 from this and compare if it falls between (2010) and (2013)

Comment: That is not valid Python; can you update that to make it a valid string, or list, or whatever the type is?

Answer (score 4):

If `lineaftersplit` is a string value, you can use the `datetime` module to parse out the information, including the year:

```
import datetime

parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(lineaftersplit, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')

if 2010 <= parsed_date.year <= 2013:
    # year between 2010 and 2013.
```

This has the advantage that you can do further tests on the `datetime` object, including sorting and date arithmetic.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> lineaftersplit="Jan 31 00:57:07 2012 GMT"
>>> parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(lineaftersplit, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')
>>> parsed_date
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 31, 0, 57, 7)
>>> parsed_date.year
2012
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.rsplit`:

```
>>> strs = 'Jan 31 00:57:07 2012 GMT'
```

`str.rstrip` will return a list like this:

```
>>> strs.rsplit(None,2)
['Jan 31 00:57:07', '2012', 'GMT']
```

Now we need the second item:

```
>>> year = strs.rsplit(None,2)[1]
>>> year
'2012'
>>> if 2010 <= int(year) <= 2013:  #apply int() to get the integer value
...     #do something
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
st="Jan 31 00:57:07 2012 GMT".split()
year=int(st[3])
```

This actually works if the string is always of this format

Comment: am getting line after split exactly like lineaftersplit=Jan 31 00:57:07 2012 GMT not with quotes 'Jan 31 00:57:07 2012 GMT'

Comment: Then use st=lineaftersplit.split()

Comment: nowyear = (now.year)
 nowyear10 = (now.year+10)
 nowyear8 = (now.year+8) if nowyear8 <= year <= nowyear10: is this right way to compare

Comment: what comparison are you talking of? Simply compare `if 2010<=year<=2013`. Where year is got from above code

Comment: Then whatever years you need, store them in two variables, say `year1` and `year2` and check it as `year1<=year<=year2`

Comment: Exactly am doing the same nowyear8 <= year <= nowyear10 which is not working

Comment: what are in `nowyear8` and `nowyear10`?

Comment: now = datetime.datetime.now()
       nowyear = (now.year) --- 2013
       nowyear10 = (now.year+10) --- 2023
       nowyear8 = (now.year+8) ---2021
after splitting lines... year = 2022, then i am checking condition if nowyear8<=year<=nowyear10:
                        print "done"

Comment: if nowyear8<=year<=nowyear10: print "done" is not working... so am asking whats wrong with this?

Comment: ya because from the `lineAfterSplit` that you suggested, year is 2012, which does not satisfy the condition. Also try printing values of year8 and year10 to check if they are the required ones

Answer (score 0):

```
 str='Jan 31 00:57:07 2012 GMT'
 str.split()[3]
```